# Calculus and Geometry Word Problem

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

The Chemist's Dilemma:

Mary, the chemist, is making a solution in her laboratory, pouring ChemA into ChemB. Mary pours 1 mg of ChemA per second into an inverted 60º cone of vertical length .5 meters containing 10 g of ChemB for 1 minute; however, she does not notice a hole at the bottom of the cone that lets 1 mg of the solution in the cone out every second. When Mary's finished, what percentage of the solution is ChemB? [Assume that ChemA and ChemB mix instantaneously and fully on touch]

In my attempts to solve this problem, I've attempted to construct an integral that would include a function determining the current percentages of ChemA and ChemB in the solution so I could calculate how much of each would be left after losing the 1 mg; however, I soon realized that function, which seemed fairly necessary to me, was actually just the original integral I was trying to find. I didn't know what to do at this recursion so I stopped there, but if anyone cares to help me (I came up with this putzing around and would just love to know the answer), it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "... into an inverted 60º cone of vertical length .5 meters containing 10 g of ChemB for **1 minute**."

Comment: Oops, silly me for missing that detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the percentage of ChemB in the fluid at time $t$ be $P(t)$. Then since we apparently start with pure ChemB the initial condition is

$$P(0)=100$$

The shape and size of the cone are irrelevant since the amount of fluid is constant and the chemicals mix instantaneously. Since $1$ mg of the $10$ g of fluid containing ChemB is lost each second (and is replaced with ChemA), the amount of ChemB loses one ten-thousandth of its previous amount each second (as a rate) . So our equation is

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=-0.0001P$$

That is an exponential decay equation, which I'm sure you can solve by separation of variables or by the usual technique for first-order linear ODEs. The ending condition in seconds is $t=60$, so evaluate

$$P(60)$$

Let me know if you cannot solve that differential equation.

(Hat tip to @Aretino: his answer reminded me that I got the units wrong in my first answer.)

Comment: "... that lets 1 mg of the **solution** in the cone out every second." Not, unfortunately, of the ChemB. Some ChemA is lost every second as well, proportionate to the output from the original function we were looking for.

Comment: In each second, $1$ mg of solution is lost, and part of that solution is ChemB. If the percentage of ChemB in the solution is $P$ then one-tenth of $P$ is lost in the second. The desired answer is limited to ChemB so I am ignoring ChemA in the equations. It might be more clear to use the *amount* of ChemB as the variable, but then we would need to convert that to the desired percentage. We lose one-tenth of the amount of ChemB each second (as an instantaneous rate).

Comment: That works for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ the quantities of ChemA and ChemB present in the cone at time $t$. Let then $v$ be the constant rate at which ChemA is poured, and also the rate at which the solution goes out of the cone. Finally, let $b_0$ be the initial quantity of ChemB in the cone.

Notice that $a(t)+b(t)=b_0$ (constant), so that the percentage of ChemB present at time $t$ is $b(t)/b_0$. It follows that we have the following differential equation for $b(t)$:
$$
{db\over dt}=-{b\over b_0}v,
$$
which has the standard solution:
$$
b(t)=b_0e^{-(v/b_0)t}.
$$
With your data: $b_0=10\ \hbox{g}=10000\ \hbox{mg}$, $v=1\ \hbox{mg}/\hbox{s}$, $t=60\ \hbox{s}$, one gets:
$$
b(t=60\ \hbox{s})=10000\cdot e^{-60/10000}\ \hbox{mg}\approx 9940\ \hbox{mg}.
$$